# Data Migration : Query to get data from JOIN tables

Tags: mysql

I migrated data from third part database to MySql Database. Table structure is as below.

```
 Job               Appointment                 Job Status
 -------------     -----------------          ---------------------
 1. Id              - Id                       - Id     
 2. Order No.       - fk_job_id                - fk_job_id   
 3. Description     - apt_no(Apt1/apt2/apt3)   - fk_apt_id
                    - apt_date                 - letter_type(letter1/Letter2/Letter3)
```

Each job has multiple appointments and relevant letter for that appointment.

e.g. for job A has appointment 1 and Letter1 is generated for that appointment.

Whenever new record is created , appoinmtent's id will be set against all letters.

Now I have migrated data where i need to set appointment id for each every letters in job_status table. I have hands on experience in excel not much in mysql. I can do this using excel and vlook.

I want to try this using SQL query. Please help me in this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I have no idea of what you really need here. Simply because I don't understand it. But since you say you can do what you need to achieve in Excel why not use MySQL for Excel?

With MySQL for Excel you can prepare all the data in Excel and subsequently upload them into MySQL.

https://www.mysql.com/de/why-mysql/windows/excel/